# Python split tuples with delimited data into new "rows/tuples"

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I currently am trying to alter a function so that it can find delimited data inside a list of tuples and split them out into additional tuples.

I'm not sure if I should be doing it this way, or a different way beforehand to add rows to the dataframe.  The underlying data is ~15 columns wide and 300k rows long...and it's growing.

Demo Data: (the second dataset contains an additional delimited list in it that causes problems in one of my solve attempts)

```
url_df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,2,5,25,26],
    'link1':['apple', 'www.google.com', 'gm@yahoo.com', 'http://www.youtube.com', '888-555-5556 Ryan Parkes rp@abc.io'],
    'link2':['http://www.bing.com','http://www.linkedin.com','',' please call now','http://www.reddit.com' ],
    'link3':['http://www.stackoverflow.com~|~http://www.ebay.com', 'http://www.imdb.com', 'http://www.google.co.uk','more random text that could be really long and annoying','over the hills and through the woods']
    })

url_df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,2,5,25,26],
    'link1':['apple', 'www.google.com', 'gm@yahoo.com', 'http://www.youtube.com', '888-555-5556 Ryan Parkes rp@abc.io'],
    'link2':['http://www.bing.com','http://www.linkedin.com','',' please call now','http://www.reddit.com~|~http://www.youtube.com~|~http://www.youtube.com' ],
    'link3':['http://www.stackoverflow.com~|~http://www.ebay.com', 'http://www.imdb.com', 'http://www.google.co.uk','more random text that could be really long and annoying','over the hills and through the woods']
    })
```

What I am doing with this data is extracting each ID, Column Name, and URL and then feeding it to another function to test if it's valid and currently active. Currently, I don't have a way to handle the delimited data, and I would like to incorporate that inside of this function:

```
for row in url_df.itertuples(name = 'Item'):
    ID = row[0]
   
    for link, col in zip(row[1:], row._fields[1:]):
        print(ID, link, col) #ideally this would have additional rows that contained the delimited links split out individually
```

I am not sure how to isolate the delimited entries in the lists of tuples, or how to create a new tuple in a list. Do the "names" have to be unique? Or can they be the same? And...how?

EG:
(Desired Output)

```
Item(Index=0, ID=1, link1='apple', link2='http://www.bing.com', link3='http://www.stackoverflow.com', link3='http://www.ebay.com')
vs
Item(Index=0, ID=1, link1='apple', link2='http://www.bing.com', link3a='http://www.stackoverflow.com', link3b='http://www.ebay.com')
```

Two attempts at breaking the data out before creating the tuples:

```
#WORKS (sort of, creates additional entry for pipe "|" as well as duplicates the other columns which would result in a massive dataset and checking the same URL multiple times.)
url_df3 =(url_df1.set_index(['ID']) 
        .apply(lambda col: col.str.split('~|~').explode())
        .reset_index()
        .reindex(url_df1.columns, axis=1))

#DOESN'T WORK - (Breaks on the list of three URL's)
url_df4 =(url_df2.set_index(['ID']) 
        .apply(lambda col: col.str.split('~|~').explode())
        .reset_index()
        .reindex(url_df2.columns, axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.str.split` on the `linkN` columns and then `.explode()` on the dataframe to produce repeated rows each with a different link.

Note that this will produce all combinations possible of links, so if you `link1` has `a~|~b` and `link2` has `c~|~d`, you’ll get rows `[('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]`:

```
>>> url_df1.set_index('ID').transform(lambda s: s.str.split(r'~\|~', expand=False)).explode('link1').explode('link2').explode('link3')
                                 link1                    link2                                              link3
ID                                                                                                                
1                                apple      http://www.bing.com                       http://www.stackoverflow.com
1                                apple      http://www.bing.com                                http://www.ebay.com
2                       www.google.com  http://www.linkedin.com                                http://www.imdb.com
5                         gm@yahoo.com                                                     http://www.google.co.uk
25              http://www.youtube.com          please call now  more random text that could be really long and...
26  888-555-5556 Ryan Parkes rp@abc.io    http://www.reddit.com               over the hills and through the woods
```

The fact that rows originate from the same entry can be identified through the repeated `ID` values.

Answer (score 0):

As @Cimbali already showed, you cannot exploded simultaneously several columns  that have different sizes. You need to do it successively.

This is a nice use case for [`pandas.DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html):

```
def pipe_explode(d):
    for col in d.columns:
        d=d.explode(col)
    return d
        
(url_df2.set_index(['ID']) 
        .apply(lambda col: col.str.split('~\|~'))
        .pipe(pipe_explode)
)
```

output:

```
                                 link1                    link2                                                    link3
ID                                                                                                                      
1                                apple      http://www.bing.com                             http://www.stackoverflow.com
1                                apple      http://www.bing.com                                      http://www.ebay.com
2                       www.google.com  http://www.linkedin.com                                      http://www.imdb.com
5                         gm@yahoo.com                                                           http://www.google.co.uk
25              http://www.youtube.com          please call now  more random text that could be really long and annoying
26  888-555-5556 Ryan Parkes rp@abc.io    http://www.reddit.com                     over the hills and through the woods
26  888-555-5556 Ryan Parkes rp@abc.io   http://www.youtube.com                     over the hills and through the woods
26  888-555-5556 Ryan Parkes rp@abc.io   http://www.youtube.com                     over the hills and through the woods
```

Alternative using `stack`+`pivot`:

```
(url_df1.set_index('ID')
 .stack().str.split('~\|~')
 .explode()
 .reset_index()
 .assign(ID2=lambda d:
         d.groupby('level_1').cumcount())
 .pivot(['ID', 'ID2'], 'level_1', 0)
 .ffill()
 .droplevel(1)
)
```

Comment: Do you think going this route would be better/faster/more efficient than figuring out how to do it with the tuples?   Also, before processing this dataframe, I would think it would be best to convert it to the ```ID, ColumnName, URL``` structure for unique entries? But that seems like it might be resource intensive?

Comment: I don't know, you have to test your alternatives and see what works best in your case. I provided you with another way, see edit.